# Error .exe application after deploy but no error when building in Powerbuilder 9

Tags: powerbuilder, system-error, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I have this unusual instance when I deployed my Powerbuilder 9 project, and run the executable file (outside the powerbuilder IDE), it prompts an error. But when I tried running it using Powerbuilder IDE, there's no error.

[image: error after deployment]

can anyone explain why this is happening? TIA

Comment: You have anonymized too much: what is the type of external object quoted in the error message?

Comment: It is likely that an object is referenced but was not included in generated .pbd. It might an object whose name is constructed at run time, and instanciated with a `create using`?

Comment: That object is a menu item and it's not constructed at run time. It's just that whenever i run it using the IDE, it runs smoothly. But by the time I deployed it, it displays an error. Is something wrong with my deployment?

Comment: Actually my question was: what is the object that is called from the clicked event of your menu? It looks like a window, but is the name of the object dynamically constructed? Is it part of a pbl that you have set to be compiled as a pbd, or is it meant to be included in main executable? In the former case is the pbd included in the deployed files?

Comment: the object is being called like this: Open(w_window); And it is not dynamically constructed and the it is included in the deployed files which is under .pbl file

Answer (score 1):

**Add the objects to your PBR file** before compiling (see PB help) along with bitmaps, datawindow objects that are needed but not directly referenced in the application.

Basically anything referenced dynamically gets left out because PB doesn't know to build-in the object. The other option you have is to **change your compile settings for the project object.** If you compile everything into one huge executable, versus compiling into an executable and PBD's (or DLL's) than PB uses different rules to determine what gets built into your runtime files.

Your problem is a very common one, and very easy to solve so good luck.